# Where do I find information around stock swaps?

Tags: stocks, corporate-acquisition

Where can I track which stock has been swapped for another, and at which ratio? Below three swaps that happened in the past years:

- SolarCity (SCTY) stock got swapped for Tesla stock (TSLA).
- Whole Foods Market (WFM) got swapped for Amazon stock (AMZN).
- LinkedIn (LNKD) got swapped for Microsoft stock (MSFT).

Comment: I don't remember the others off the top of my head but Amazon paid cash for Whole Foods.  WFM shareholders didn't receive AMZN shares they received dollars.

Comment: Do you have access to Bloomberg, Thomson Reuters or CAPITAL IQ?

Comment: aren't you essentially looking for a list of recent mergers and the subset of them that result in at least part of the transaction being a stock swap? what is the purpose of gathering the list and the details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The category is called Mergers & Acquisitions.  There are numerous web sites that provide such information.  For example, the Online Investor provides a running list of the most recent 100 of them with a link to the details.

https://www.theonlineinvestor.com/mergers/

You can also monitor the Delisted list at the major stock exchanges.  For example, theNASDAQ posts a page daily list of them.  Under the column "Reason" you would look for "Acquisition/Merger"

https://listingcenter.nasdaq.com/IssuersPendingSuspensionDelisting.aspx

If you want historical lists by the year, Google: "Mergers & Acquisitions Wiki 2017".  Change the year as necessary.